# Upgrading from slot-scope to v-slot breaks without errors

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I'm trying to upgrade from the [old `slot-scope` syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots-with-the-slot-scope-Attribute) to the relatively [new `v-slot` syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) but it doesn't seem to work.

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Go to the `Form.vue` file in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuelidate-error-in-slot-syntax-upgrade-ly1rjg?file=/src/components/Form.vue)
2. To see it working using the old `slot-scope` syntax, just let the app compile and use the login form (enter some text in both the fields)
3. Uncomment lines 5, 18, 23, and 36 and comment lines 6, 19, 24, and 37
4. Use the login form again. The inputs disappear as soon as you start typing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#ad) in FormGroup.vue returns more than one VNode. Try that:

```
render(createElement) {
  return createElement(
    "div",
    this.$scopedSlots.default({
      errors: this.errors,
      invalid: this.invalid,
    })
  );
}
```